# Constante indefinida

Tags: php

tengo este problema con una constante indefinida quiero quitar la advertencia que me genera esta constante,  ya que no puedo afectar el código que estoy utilizando me pueden ayudar por favor muchas gracias por su ayuda
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Remueve el `!` antes de `defined('API_SII_DURACION_TOKEN')`...

Comment: el error perciste en la constante

Comment: El error marca la misma línea o en otra?

Comment: en la misma linea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En lugar de tu bloque `if ... else` puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
defined('API_SII_DURACION_TOKEN') or define('API_SII_DURACION_TOKEN', 60);
```

Esto hará que la constante sea igual a `60` si no está definida, que es el sentido que veo en tu código.

Y, **muy importante**, usar en lo adelante `API_SII_DURACION_TOKEN`, también en ese contexto, en vez de la variable `$minutos_token`.

Comment: si la constante no esta en un if sino en un arreglo como podria omitir la advertencia

Comment: @JesusSanchez no entiendo tu duda. Sugiero que pongas un ejemplo basado en código del caso que expones. Considera poner el texto del código, no capturas de imagen, lo cual no sirve para reproducir el problema y dificulta analizarlo.

Comment: Hola disculpa en esta parte a que te refieres --> Y, muy importante, usar en lo adelante API_SII_DURACION_TOKEN, también en ese contexto, en vez de la variable $minutos_token. no entendi esa pequeña parte

Comment: @JesusSanchez me refiero a que si te preocupas por que la constante esté definida, y si no lo está la defines, debería ser para luego usar esa constante y es que no tendría sentido eso si luego, por otra parte usas también `$minutos_token`, sería una especie de redundancia.